# How to convert XML to JSON with react

Tags: json, react-native, xml-parsing, expo

I have an API that provides me XML data, and i want to convert that XML data from the API into JSON. Can anyone help me wiht that problem?

I'm using Expo to creat a app. I tried to use nodemoduls, but when i tried that I alwas get an error "It failed because React Native does not include the Node standard library" The code belwo dosen't work

```
import { View, Text, ActivityIndicator } from 'react-native'
import { fetch } from "fetch";
const furl = 'https://skimap.org/Regions/view/346.xml';
const xmlToJson = require('xml-to-json-stream');
const parser = xmlToJson({attributeMode: true});

export default class RegionList extends PureComponent {

    state = { regions: [] };
    async componentWillMount() {
        fetch(furl).then(response => parser.xmlToJson(response, (err,json)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            }
        }))
        .then( (response) => this.setState({regions: response}));

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import {Xml2Json} from 'react-native-xml-to-json';
        
fetch(furl).then(response =>     
    Xml2Json.toJson(response, data => {
        console.log("Data = ", data);
    }).then( (response) => this.setState({regions: data})
);
```